# Default route being added randomly while NIC is already up, post-up action doesn't help

Tags: networking, routing, gateway

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 machine that I'm using as a temporary router while I fix some issues with my normal router.

The network looks like this:

[image: Network diagram]

Thus, the normal flow of traffic out to the internet would be from 192.168.10.2 (my workstation), through the 192.168.10.203 interface on the Ubuntu machine, forwarded out the 192.168.0.20 interface.

My normal routing table looks like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    203    0        0 ens192
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     203    0        0 ens192
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     204    0        0 ens224
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 ens160
```

The routing works perfectly fine, however, the issue I'm running into is that every now and again, one (or both) of the following routes will get added at random, breaking my workstation's access to the internet:

```
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.99    0.0.0.0         UG    204    0        0 ens224
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.99    0.0.0.0         UG    204    0        0 ens224
```

This is the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens160
iface ens160 inet static
        address 192.168.10.203
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.10.99
        metric 100
        post-up ip route del 0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.10.99

auto ens192
iface ens192 inet static
        address 192.168.0.20
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1

auto ens224
iface ens224 inet static
        address 192.168.1.20
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.99
        metric 100
        post-up ip route del 0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.1.99
```

For some reason, those `post-up` commands also don't always seem to work (sometimes the 192.168.1.99 gateway will remain after restarting the `networking` service, and sometimes the 192.168.10.99 gateway will remain).

Removing the `gateway` statements for `ens160` and `ens224` unfortunately doesn't solve the issue.

It's not like the errant default routes are being added to allow traffic to be routed to those networks, because all three networks already have routes in place to go through the correct interface.

Any ideas?

---

EDIT:

Tried removing everything but the `address` statements for the non-primary interfaces `ens160` and `ens224`, but now routes are being added for those interfaces to go through `192.168.1.99`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens160
iface ens160 inet static
        address 192.168.10.203

auto ens192
iface ens192 inet static
        address 192.168.0.20
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1

auto ens224
iface ens224 inet static
        address 192.168.1.20
```

Resultant output of `route -n` after running `sudo systemctl restart networking`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.99    0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 ens160
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    203    0        0 ens192
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.99    0.0.0.0         UG    204    0        0 ens224
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     203    0        0 ens192
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 ens160
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     204    0        0 ens224
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens160
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm not understanding that article or if I didn't explain my problem clearly - I only want a single default gateway, but my machine is inadvertently inserting routes for additional gateways.

Comment: Like I said, if I remove the `gateway` items for the two secondary/tertiary interfaces (ens160 and ens224), the routes to those two gateways still end up in the routing table.

Comment: Correct!  But, they don't work unless you use iproute2.  I have never by default been able successfully to get more than one gateway working.  I am also working around 1,000's of servers everyday.

Comment: But I don't want more than one gateway...

Comment: It should work fine if you remove everything after `netmask` in each section that you don't want a gateway in.

Comment: That did it, thanks Terrance. Looks like I should have better articulated what the expected behaviour was, so apologies for that.

Comment: It's OK.  It took me a second to realize exactly what you were doing too.  My apologies as well.  =)

Comment: Well I take it back... It didn't work. Now it's just adding garbage routes out of the two interfaces without netmasks/gateways. Both ens160 and ens224 are trying to route through 192.168.1.99 as the default route.

Comment: Did you remove the netmask lines?

Comment: Yep - updated /etc/network/interfaces edited into the OP

Comment: The netmask lines are needed.  Each section should be at least address and netmask.  Netmask is what tells the OS that all IPs from 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254 are in the same network.  Same goes with the other section.

Comment: My comment was "It should work fine if you remove everything after netmask in each section that you don't want a gateway in. – Terrance 12 mins ago   "

Comment: That's what I did - the primary interface (ens192) still has a `netmask` and `gateway` line. I only removed the `netmask` and `gateway` for the other interfaces as you suggested.

Comment: Yes, the primary sections needs it as well as the other 2 sections.  Add the netmask lines back!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107307/discussion-between-resetack-and-terrance).

Comment: Now I'm confused... You just said that if I don't want an interface to have a gateway (a default route), that I should remove the netmask and gateway lines for that interface.

Comment: \*after\* netmask.... *facepalm*